# Adding class to form-item

Tags: 6, theming, forms

I've been trying to add a custom classname to a form-item to use as a 'marker' for theming with my css file.

I've been on stackexchange/overflow and several other sites and forums, including the Drupal documentation, but found no reason why it shouldn't work.

Official documentation state the use of the attribute tag like so:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => 'myclass'),
```

But as seen in my example below, this doesn't work or give me errors.

[image: screenshot]

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

[#attributes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#attributes) is not supported by [item](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/6#item) form elements.

> #### item
>
> **Description:** Generate a display-only form element allowing for an optional title and description.
>
> **Note:** since this is a read-only field, setting the #required property will do nothing except theme the form element to look as if it were actually required (i.e. by placing a red star next to the #title).
>
> **Properties:** #access, #after_build, #description, #element_validate, #parents, #post_render, #prefix, #pre_render, #required, #suffix, #theme, #title, #tree, #type, #value, #weight

You would then need to add a custom theme call such as:

`function MYTHEME_preprocess_form_element(&$vars) {
  $vars['#attributes']['class'][] = 'another-class';
}`

Comment: You're absolutely correct, how could i've not seen this.
However this puts me even further from my end goal :(

I did however found a different article here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012870/remove-class-form-item-from-drupal-forms) that could help me, but i think i'm doing something wrong with it.

I created a file named sgv_inschrijving_node_form.tpl.php (same name as the file in the module that renders the form) in the template folder of my theme with the following code: http://i.snag.gy/doRBg.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solved it by adding code to the .module file. I wrapped a div with class around the content.

Comment: If you are adding code to core module files, this is a very very bad idea. You will no longer be able to update this module without your site breaking.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `_form_set_class()`

Docs: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/_form_set_class/6.x

Example:

```
_form_set_class($element, array('my-class'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that although you cannot use `#attributes` with `'#type' => 'item'`, you can use `#wrapper_attributes`.

See https://github.com/backdrop/backdrop-issues/issues/3817 for details/background.

Answer (score -1):

for the future, if you use the #attributes, wrap the class name(s) in an array like this:

```
'#attributes' => array('class' => array('myclass', 'otherclass')),
```

Comment: This is not an answer for OPs query.

Comment: Plus the OP asks for a Drupal 6 solution, this would be for Drupal 7 only